# How to add many components to a JFrame in a format

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a JPanel, 4 ComboBoxes, and a button. I want to have a 700 x 500 JFrame, with the panel taking up the left 500 x 500.  The right side I want, vertically, 2 combo boxes, another 2 combo boxes, and then the button. Hopefully this makes sense: I just want to have them all visible and I want the boxes paired in groups of 2. Example code of what I've tried is here:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Test extends JFrame{

public Test () {
    super();
    //setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel canvas = new JPanel();
    canvas.setBackground(Color.red);
    canvas.setSize(500, 500);
    JComboBox field1 = new JComboBox();
    JComboBox field2 = new JComboBox();
    JComboBox field3 = new JComboBox();
    JComboBox field4 = new JComboBox();      
    JButton button = new JButton();
    JPanel info = new JPanel();
    info.setBackground(Color.blue);
    info.add(field1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    info.add(field2, BorderLayout.EAST);
    info.add(field3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    info.add(field4, BorderLayout.WEST);
    info.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(info, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(canvas, BorderLayout.WEST);
    setTitle("TEST");
setSize(700, 500);
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    JFrame testFrame = new Test();
    testFrame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Any help or suggestions about how to go about laying this out would be great.

Comment: Getting an absolute size isn't gong to (easily) achievable, but, you could use a GridLayout, BoxLayout or GridBagLayout to achieve the basic concept. Take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more ideas

Answer (score 1):

If you want your combo buttons and the button vertically stacked on top of each other, I would use a grid layout instead of a border layout. Just make the border layout have 1 column and 5 rows.